# changing characters in a csv-File via perl - Error

Tags: windows, perl

I try the following code in a cmd-line-box on a Windows-Server.

```
perl -p -i -e 's/\n/\r\n/g' \\server-dns\test\*.csv
```

But that doesn't work.

Error-Code is:

```
Can't open: \\server-dns\test\*.csv: Invalid Argument.
```

I'm a absolutely newbie. Can anyone help me.

TIA

Auric

Comment: Why would you want to change line endings? It is unlikely that this will solve what you think it will solve. Also, on Windows, you need to supply a backup when using `-i`, e.g. `-i.bak`.

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't do globing, so you may do this manually,

```
perl -i~ -pe 'BEGIN{@ARGV = map glob, @ARGV} s/\n/\r\n/g' \\server-dns\test\*.csv
```

Also under windows you may have to use backup file instead of in place edit when using `-i`

Comment: I use `@ARGV = map glob, @ARGV` to accommodate multiple args.

Comment: @TLP tnx for comment.